# Robo-reviewers census

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Is there any data on the characteristics of edits robo-reviewers? There is a lot of discussion on how to tackle this problem, but I think knowing "the enemy" should come first, so better targeted approaches can be designed.

The first thing would be to know the reputation distributions. As the edit queue is empty but the close is over 11 000, they ought to be somewhere between 2 and 3k rep; but it seems a quite narrow margin.

Other data point would be how they got their reputation, and possible badges. This could help weighting the votes casted by users likely to be robo-reviewers or not.

How to identify them? My SQL skills are close to none, so I can't really do it. I would classify a robo-reviewer candidate based on:

- Number of reviews in the last month.
- Median time to decide.
- Approved / rejected ratio.
- Failed audits.

Comment: I've seen 10k robo-reviewers.

Comment: Also 50k robo-reviewers...

Comment: So, reputation is not a very good metric. Knowing more about this guys we could think of better designed conditions, like "having at least so much score in accepted answers from good enough questions".

Comment: Reputation is a very good metric, it's just not absolute. The lower the rep, the more robo reviewers there are. It would be interesting to see how many there are procentually in each rep-range compared to the total amount of reviewers in that range, but I doubt it would give a different view.

Comment: As for the metrics: approve/reject ratio, failed audits and skipped posts ratio would be the best way to calculate it I believe.

Comment: I do not think skipped posts are useful for this.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't think skips are recorded at all. I know I've skipped the same review 3 times in one session, so I think if they were recorded, it wouldn't have shown up again for me (at least not so soon).

Comment: I do think skipped posts would be useful for this (although I agree I doubt they are recorded). Certainly someone with a 25% skip rate would be incredibly unlikely to be a robo (although if we turned it into a known metric for review quality we'd suddenly see skips go through the roof - with would probably be a good thing). Even if the difference is 0% skips for your average robo, and 1% for a decent reviewer I'm sure there'd be some difference.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel _reputation is a very good metric_ I challenge that statement. It can be close to a good one, but the false positives (bad reviewers classified as reputable ergo good ones) is too high. My whole intention with this question is to gather some hard data and improve the metrics.

Comment: @OGHaza I agree that this could be very useful as it stands, but as soon as robo-reviewers are aware of that fact, they can easily change the algorithm to skip the appropriate amount of posts

Comment: @neelsg, true, so it would become redundant as a measure of who is a robo, but us regular reviewers would still enjoy seeing x% less blind-approvals :P If only the robos could get their gold badge just by skipping, then at least they wouldn't be approving terrible edits

Comment: Not edits, but I had a look at 2 randomly selected all-time top reviewers in the first post queue. Both had downvoted less than 1% of their all time votes and closer to half a percent of the number of reviews they have done.

Answer (score 3):

I actually asked this [question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262102/1877903), but it think it may also be a valid answer to your question.

You could detect robo-reviewers based on what happened to reviewed posts in retrospect. If a lot of "No Action Needed" posts end up getting severely downvoted or flagged, that should be quite obvious to pick up.