# Automated retrospective detection for robo-reviewers

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-abuse

Based on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261987/1877903) and the comments thereon as well as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260220/1877903), it is clear that review audits fail to detect robo-reviewers properly.

Should there not be some kind of automated detection of robo-reviewers based on what happened to reviewed posts in retrospect. If a lot of "No Action Needed" posts end up getting severely downvoted or flagged, that should be quite obvious to pick up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Based on this question and the comments thereon as well as this question, it is clear that review audits fail to detect robo-reviewers properly.

As I explain in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260350/19679), true "robo-reviewers" are indeed caught by the audits consistently. These are the people who blindly click a single button over and over. That term was originally introduced before audits came on the scene, and I don't believe it applies to the problematic reviewers we are talking about now. Someone who simply clicks a button over and over will be caught by audits after a certain point (although I wish they would [start with audits earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214541/give-new-edit-reviewers-some-audits-to-begin-with/214542#214542) to catch these people before they're allowed to do any damage). The escalating review bans eventually drive off almost all of these people, or get them to convert to actual reviewers. The rest we deal with via measures up to and including suspensions.

The arguments that people are having now are about bad or careless reviewers, not people gaming the system. For example, several of the reviewers pointed out in the linked questions (in comments that I've since removed) actually flagged many non-answers and spam correctly, despite the few bad reviews that people pointed out. Normal people don't see these reviews, since the posts that were flagged ended up deleted. This skews the perception of folks like this, making it seem like they approve everything.

It's not that audits aren't detecting true "robo-reviewers" (they are, in almost all cases), it's that we're trying to figure out ways of dealing with people making bad calls in review. It's a little more nuanced when you have reviewers who make the right decision many times, but then approve things that others disagree with. Some people think certain minor edits are acceptable, where others don't. Some people think code edits to fix problems are acceptable, where others don't.

Is the solution more nuanced audits? I don't know.

We have [talked about something like your suggestion before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223212/135615), where reviewers who approve content that later is deleted as spam or a non-answer could be identified for further review. It might be worth examining as a means of picking out reviewers who are just squeaking by the audits (or have found a way to game them, as some people do).

I'm actually liking how things have worked in the new Low Quality Posts review queue, where the large number of reviewers required for a post to pass review has avoided many of the problems with individual bad reviews. I think that a good first step to improve the Late Answers and First Posts review queues might be to increase the number of reviews required per item. I know that there have been concerns about this skewing votes for posts in those queues, but I don't see much of that in the Low Quality Posts queue now.